# Menu Navigations

Tags: c

My friend requested a navigation menu for his code that he has since he didn't really know how to do it, so I had created one for him. I just wanted to get it reviewed since I'm a beginner with C and want to see if there is any way to shorten or improve this.

```
//
//  main.c
//  Oyster Top Up Menu
//
//  Created by JStudent

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    /* Variable Sets */

    char firstname[21];
    char lastname[21];

    int menuselect;
    int oystnumber[11];
    int oystregnumber[11];
    int oystadminnumber = 1621941;

    /*****************/


    printf("1. Register Oyster Card\n");
    printf("2. Login with Oyster Card > ");
    scanf("%d", &menuselect);

        switch(menuselect) {

            case 1 :

                printf("Please enter your first name: ");
                scanf("%20s", firstname);

                //system("cls");

                printf("Please enter your last name: ");
                scanf("%20s", lastname);

                //system("cls");

                printf("Enter your 10 Digit Oyster Card Number: ");
                scanf("%10d", oystregnumber);

                break;

            case 2 :

                printf("Please enter your 10 Digit Oyster Card Number: ");
                scanf("%10d", oystnumber);

                if (oystnumber == oystregnumber) {

                    printf("Welcome, %s %s.", firstname, lastname);

                } else if (oystnumber == oystadminnumber) {

                    printf("Welcome, Admin!");
                }

                break;

    }

    return 0;
}

/* Remember to learn how to repeat the switch menu after break; */
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is technically broken.

An attempt to compile gives two notable warnings:

```
foo.c:41:32: warning: array comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
            if (oystnumber == oystregnumber) {
                           ^
foo.c:43:39: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int *' and 'int')
            } else if (oystnumber == oystadminnumber) {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`oystnumber` and `oystregnumber` are indeed declared as arrays, and only the first elements are ever used (`scanf("%10d", oystregnumber)` reads into `oystregnumber[0]`). Declare them as integers:

```
    int oystregnumber;
```

and read them also as integers:

```
    scanf("%10d", &oystregnumber);
```

---

Another problem is that when a `Login` option is selected, the code prints garbage: `firstname` and `lastname` are not initialized.

---

There are more potential problems, but they are irrelevant until you "learn how to repeat the switch menu after break".